# Synchronisation of a counter

Tags: java

I try to learn something about multithreading and tried myself on a multithreaded counter. For my knowledge, I synchronized the counter variables but I encounter the following problems:

1. The threads do not take alternating turns
2. The counter does not count as intended (eg from 337 to 339 or from 344 to 344)

Can anyone please explain, what I did wrong?

**Class RunThreads**

```
public class RunThreads {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread1();        
    Thread thread2 = new Thread2();

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();                    
    }
}
```

**Class Thread1**

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
public void run(){
    while (ThreadCount.counter < 1000){
        ThreadCount.incrementCounter();
        ThreadCount.printCounter(this);

        try{
            notifyAll();
            wait();

       }
       catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
}
```

**class Thread2** (Yes I don't need two separate classes but it makes it easier for me to understand)

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {
public void run(){
    while (ThreadCount.counter < 1000){
        ThreadCount.incrementCounter();            
        ThreadCount.printCounter(this);

        try{
            notifyAll();
            wait();   

       }
       catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
}
```

**class ThreadCount**

```
public class ThreadCount {    

public static int counter = 0;

public static synchronized void  incrementCounter(){
    counter++;

}

public static void decrementCounter(){
    counter--;
}

public static synchronized void  printCounter(Thread t){;      
    Output.append(t.getName() + ":" + counter + "\n");
}    
}
```

**class Output**

```
public class Output{
public static String value = "";     

public static synchronized void append(String s) {
    value+=s;
}
 }
```

Comment: Adding some sample output would help give readers more context as to what exactly is happening.

Comment: Why does having two separate classes make it easier to understand? I ask because if you're confused between classes and instances - which it seems you are - you are a long way from getting to concurrency. I strongly suggest you get a good grip on the basics before moving onto advanced topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This demonstrates the pitfalls of swallowing exceptions.  If you caught the exceptions in your threads and simply output them, you would observe the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.notifyAll
    at Thread2.run
```

This will happen when you call `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll` on an object (the `Thread` objects, in this case) where you don't hold the lock by means of `synchronized`.

If you create a common object that both threads synchronize on, and call `wait`/`notifyAll` on, you will get what you are observing.  For example:

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        synchronized (ThreadCount.lockObj) {
            while (ThreadCount.counter < 1000) {
                ThreadCount.incrementCounter();
                ThreadCount.printCounter(this);

                try {
                    ThreadCount.lockObj.notifyAll();
                    ThreadCount.lockObj.wait();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. I moved the try/catch block to the ThreadCount Object

Comment: That works too.  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The increment and the print are done in two separate operations.

So you can have (for example)

- thread1: increment from 342 to 343
- thread2: increment from 343 to 344
- thread2: print 344
- thread1: print 344

Regarding the alternating turns: both threads call wait() and notifyAll() on themselves (so, on two separate objects), and do so without holding their lock, which throws an exception. And since you ignore exceptions, you can't notice the error you made. Never ignore exceptions. Do not catch Exception.

To have alternating turns, the `incrementCounter()` method could look like this:

```
private static boolean turn;

public static synchronized void incrementCounter(){
    counter++;
    printCounter(Thread.currentThread());

    turn = !turn;
    boolean nextTurn = !turn;

    ThreadCount.class.notifyAll();
    while (turn != nextTurn) {
        try {
            ThreadCount.class.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The turn boolean and the while loop might look averkill, but they're in fact necessary if you want your code to work as expected even in case of spurious wakeups.

Comment: So calling the printCounter method from within the incrementCounter method should work?

Comment: It would make sure that you don't print duplicates and don't have holes in the sequence. But it won't ensure alternating turns.

Comment: Okay. Thanks: Halfway there then: How can I get the turns?

Answer (score 0):

```
*Thread1* ThreadCount.incrementCounter();
*Thread2* ThreadCount.incrementCounter();

*Thread1* ThreadCount.printCounter(this);
*Thread2* ThreadCount.printCounter(this);
```

In this action Thread 1 increment by 2 and Thread2 increment by 0.

You can use AtomicInteger etc for thread-safe operations.

You should encapsulate int. Don't leave public.